# How to responsive Absulute Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

**This is my Java code.How can i Responsive this page for all android device?**
i have also an xml code...which is show in below.
I'm trying to much but i can not do this..
I'm beginner in Android.
My main motive is responsive the following page.
By the way i fixed it only for few device.
i fixed this view in xml but i think it's main problem is the Java code.

```
public void fill_grid()
{
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        int text=cells.get(i);
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams =
                (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)buttons[text].getLayoutParams();
        switch(i)
        {case(0):

            absParams.x = 15;
            absParams.y = 15;
            buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
            break;
            case(1):

                absParams.x = 170;
                absParams.y = 15;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
            case(2):

                absParams.x = 325;
                absParams.y = 15;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
            case(3):

                absParams.x = 15;
                absParams.y = 185;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
            case(4):

                absParams.x =170;
                absParams.y =185;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
            case(5):

                absParams.x =325;
                absParams.y =185;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
            case(6):

                absParams.x = 15;
                absParams.y = 355;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
            case(7):

                absParams.x = 170;
                absParams.y = 355;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
            case(8):

                absParams.x = 325;
                absParams.y = 355;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;


        }
```

> This is my xml File...i think it's not 100% ok but i tried so much..i am searching more and more how to solve it but i can not find it....

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/GameField"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:textAlignment="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button00"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="15dp"
        android:layout_y="15dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="135dp"
        android:layout_y="15dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="255dp"
        android:layout_y="15dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="15dp"
        android:layout_y="150dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button04"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="135dp"
        android:layout_y="150dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button05"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="255dp"
        android:layout_y="150dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button06"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="15dp"
        android:layout_y="285dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button07"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="135dp"
        android:layout_y="285dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="48sp">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button08"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_x="255dp"
        android:layout_y="285dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    </Button>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` has been deprecated for **six years**. Please do not use it.

Comment: what can i used for this code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into Linear Layouts or Relative Layouts to learn about making responsive UI.

For your specific scenario, I'd use a [GridLayout][1]

These layouts excel at showing items in grid just like you want.

You really want to avoid specifying the exact coordinates of your views like your switch statement is doing. Most of the spacing work can be done in your layout.

Here is the sample activity I've created that contains a GridView and its adapter.

```
public class RelativeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_relative);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new NumberGridAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers))));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(RelativeActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private class NumberGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private List<String> values;
        private Context context;

        public NumberGridAdapter(Context c, List<String> numbers) {
            context = c;
            values = numbers;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return values.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text_view);
            tv.setText(""+position);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout with the GridView: activity_relative.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        />
```

And here is the layout file that each grid cell uses: grid_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Gridview settings are in the xml and the adapater. You can load any kind of data you want into it. I have set the number of columns to three but you can use any number you want. This is the first step towards making a more responsive view.

**EDIT**: Stack Overflow isn't really the place that people do work for you. They just give you the answer to your problem. You have to apply that answer for yourself. That's the only way to learn.

Here's what you would do for your project.

1. Get rid of the buttons you defined manually in the xml.
2. Replace the AbsoluteLayout with a GridView.
3. Create an adapter for a GridView in your Game Activity
4. Give the Adapter an array of Buttons
5. Change the logic of your move(Button) function to just change the grid view items

Here's the changes I made to your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/Game"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- THIS VIEW REPLACES YOUR ABSOLUTE LAYOUT & ALL THE BUTTONS -->
    <!-- DEFINE THE BUTTONS IN CODE AND ADD THEM TO THE GRIDVIEW ADAPTER -->
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/GameField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MoveText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/moves_title"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/GameField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MoveCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/MoveText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/GameField"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/MoveText"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#010101">

    </TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And I made some changes to the Game activity:

```
onCreate() {
....

  GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GameField);
        gridview.setAdapter(new NumberGridAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(buttons)));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Game.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private class NumberGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<Button> values;
        private Context context;

        public NumberGridAdapter(Context c, List<Button> numbers) {
            context = c;
            values = numbers;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return values.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text_view);
            tv.setText(""+position);


            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    makeMove(values.get(position));
                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }
    }




    public Button[] findButtons() {
        Button[] b = new Button[9];

        b[0] = new Button(this);
        b[0].setText("0");
        b[0].setId(R.id.Button00);

        b[1] = new Button(this);
        b[0].setText("1");
        b[1].setId(R.id.Button01);


        b[2] = new Button(this);
        b[2].setText("2");
        b[2].setId(R.id.Button02);

        b[3] = new Button(this);
        b[3].setText("3");
        b[3].setId(R.id.Button03);

        b[4] = new Button(this);
        b[4].setText("4");
        b[4].setId(R.id.Button04);

        b[5] = new Button(this);
        b[5].setText("5");
        b[5].setId(R.id.Button05);

        b[6] = new Button(this);
        b[6].setText("6");
        b[6].setId(R.id.Button06);

        b[7] = new Button(this);
        b[7].setText("7");
        b[7].setId(R.id.Button07);

        b[8] = new Button(this);
        b[8].setText("8");
        b[8].setId(R.id.Button08);

        return b;
    }
```

Comment: in that link i have my full project. Can u please help me how to solve this project responsive. Please give me the feedback

Comment: I can't write the program for you but I've given you the solution you can apply. See my latest edit. Good luck!